# WPF Animation stops spontaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a WPF application which contains a UserControl, whose border is animated:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.AlarmItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=Alarm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type cs:AlarmItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="5" 
            Height="100"
            Name="Border" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="100">
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="FlashingStoryboard"
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="Black" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlashStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FlashingOn"
                             Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FlashingStoryboard}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="FlashingOff" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" 
                   Name="AlarmImage" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:AlarmItem}}}" 
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <cs:ResponseTimer Expired="Timer_Expired"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              HideIfExpired="True"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              MinHeight="10"
                              x:Name="TheTimer"
                              TimeoutPeriod="00:02:30"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The application receives data from a proprietary device my company manufactures.  The objects are received and loaded into a View Model class instance.  A new instance of this control is created for each object received, a reference to the view model is put into the new control instance's `DataContext` property, and the new control is added to a `ListBox` in a `Window`.

The animation is supposed to run while the object's status property is a particular value.  There's a second status value where the animation is also supposed to run, and the status changes to that value after a fixed time interval in which the user has not responded to that item.  The animation is only supposed to stop when the status takes on a value that can only be set by user interaction.

When the first object is received & displayed, the animation works fine.  If no further objects are received, the animation keeps running & the border color changes as intended when the timer expires.

However, the animation just stops, on its own, after 2 or more objects are received.  This is both before the timer that changes the status that causes the border color to change expires and before any user action is taken.  Note that it doesn't always stop on the second object, it sometimes takes receiving 3 or 4 objects before the animation stops.

Does anyone have any idea why the animation stops?  How do I keep each one running to the end?  Is there a better way to get the same effect that doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Has anybody else had a problem like this?

Comment: is it possible for you to post a full working sample? code provided is not sufficient enough. or at-least provide a way to simulate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to information from kidshaw, I was able to figure out a solution that works. Essentially, the animation is supposed to switch the `Border` control's `BorderBrush` back and forth between two colors, black and a color that depends upon the properties of the object in the `DataContext`.  This logic is in the code behind because the logic depends on two different properties of the data context object and I couldn't come up with a XAML trigger that would work properly.  It wasn't included in the original question because it didn't seem pertinent.

As mentioned in the comments to kidshaw's answer, the problem was that the animation was losing track of what color the `BorderBrush` was supposed to be when additional alerts came into the window.  Instead of switching back & forth between Red & Black, for example, it would think it had to switch between black & black or red & red.  So it looked like no animation was taking place, when it actually was.

To fix the problem, and because of the need to choose the color based on properties of the object in the data context, I ended up adding a second `DiscreteColorKeyFrame` to the animation for the other color.  I tried to use a bind the `Value` property of the `DiscreteColorKeyFrame` to a `DependencyProperty` I added to the control which would be set by the code behind logic, but that didn't work.  The animation kept switching back & forth between black & transparent, while the Output window in VS kept recording errors about `CanFreeze` being false.

So I ended up making one animation for each different color and adding one `VisualState` to the `VisualStateManager` for each color.  There were changes in the code behind, too, bu tI got it all working.

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.AlarmItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=Alarm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type cs:AlarmItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="5" 
            Height="100"
            Name="Border" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="100">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="AnimatedBrush" Color="Black" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ExpiredAnimation"
                        AutoReverse="False"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:01"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBrush"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFFFFF78" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="Black" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="HistoricalAnimation"
                        AutoReverse="False"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:01"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBrush"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"   Value="#FFFFFF78" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="Black" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="PendingAnimation"
                        AutoReverse="False"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:01"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBrush"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Red" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="Black" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="WhiteListAnimation"
                        AutoReverse="False"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:01"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBrush"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FF5819" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="Black" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>

        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlashStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="ExpiredState"    Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ExpiredAnimation}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="HistoricalState" Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HistoricalAnimation}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PendingState"    Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PendingAnimation}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="WhiteListState"  Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WhiteListAnimation}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="FlashingOff" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" 
                   Name="AlarmImage" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:AlarmItem}}}" 
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <cs:ResponseTimer Expired="Timer_Expired"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              HideIfExpired="True"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              MinHeight="10"
                              x:Name="TheTimer"
                              TimeoutPeriod="00:02:30"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the code from the backend that picks & starts the correct animation.

```
private void StartStatusAnimation() {
    if ( condition1 ) {
        // It is.  Display the WhiteListAnimation.
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "WhiteListState", true ) ) {
            // Log error
        }
    } else if ( condition2 ) {
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "ExpiredState", true ) ) {
            // Log error
        }

    } else if ( condition3 ) {
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "HistoricalState", true ) ) {
            // Log error
        }
    } else if ( condition4 ) {
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "PendingState", true ) ) {
            // Log error
        }
    } else {
        // We don't know what state this is.  Stop flashing now
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "FlashingOff", true ) ) {
            // Log error
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the values of the data context objects properties can change due to user interaction, or a timer expiring, which would either stop the flashing all together, in the first case, or cause the current animation to stop and another one to start, in the second.  In the second case, the `VisualSTateManager` is just set to the `FlashingOff` state when the trigger in the `Style` sets the control's `IsFlashing` to false, and in the second, the above method is called again when the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

The closest scenario I've had to this is triggering an animation based upon a value in the view model. I'm taking the 'better way' option here so apologies if this doesn't fit with your solution, I'm just basing it on what I see.

Now you mention a new control is created for each alert that comes from your external device? So I'm going to assume this control is bound to a single instance and presented in something like a listbox.

If you're still with me, your control instance has it's own view model instance and by the looks of it, your triggering from an IsPending and IsExpired property such that when either is true, make it flash.

First thing I'd do is simplify that binding from the ViewModel adding as IsAlertRequired property which you set when you require the alert - can be updated in the setter for you existing properties. The reason here is that a single trigger is way easier than a multibinding.

Then use DataTrigger to start your storyboard. In your app add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and then import them in your XAML:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then add a trigger before your layoutroot element:

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewModel.IsAlertRequired}" Value="True">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashingAnimation}"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
```

That should start your animation based upon a view model data binding.

Assuming you get that far and it works for starting your animation, if it still stops then I would look into whether something within your viewmodel or external component is blocking the UI thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  The animation **appears** to stop right now.  By that I mean that the `Border` control's `BorderBrush` stops changing colors.  It's my assumption that it has stopped, but it might be running & something else is broken. Like the control may be forgetting one of the brushes its supposed to be switching between.  That just occurred to me.  I'll have to inspect the animation using Snoop to check that out, I guess.

Comment: I'm getting "The name "Interaction" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"." Where am I supposed to put that trigger?

Comment: You should put the xmlns in the control root tag, the very first one in the xaml, there should be other similar. Add a reference in your project to Microsoft.expression.interactivity. Finally, the trigger goes after your usercontrol.resources and before your border.

Comment: If it stops and your UI is still responsive, such as buttons still press or text boxes still edit, then it's a safe bet the animation has completed.

Comment: The animation has `RepeatBehavior` set to `Forever`  It shouldn't stop until my code tells it to stop by changing the visual state.  Which it hasn't.  And the UI is still responsive.  I'm betting that it's the animation starting with the wrong color value in the `Border.BorderBrush` property's `SolicColorBrosu.Color`.

Comment: That's possible. You could add a <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="White" /> to your animation

Comment: That's it.  The problem is that the animation loses track of what the color should be when another alert is received.  Since you're the only one to respond, I'll give you the bounty anyway, though I'll post my own solution, when I've got it working.

Comment: You're very kind. Glad I was able to provide a sounding board for you. Enjoy your animated alert!